# SQL CASE and WHER and join

Tags: mysql

I write a sql like this

```
"SELECT (
    CASE WHEN (1.00 - sys_pay.org_rate)*trans.txn_amt as agent_pay_current 
    < (trans.txn_amt - sys_pay.org_rate_limit) as agent_pay_max 
    THEN agent_pay_max 
    ELSE agent_pay_current END),
    FROM sys_org 
    INNER JOIN trans ON sys_org.mid = trans.mid 
    INNER JOIN sys_pay ON sys_pay.mid = sys_org.mid 
    ORDER BY txn_date DESC limit 10"
```

It said I had an error in SQL syntax,How to make this correct?

Comment: what's the error? any message?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as agent_pay_current < (trans.txn_amt - sys_pay.org_rate_limit) as agent_pay_max' at line 1"

Comment: MySQL? and you have tagged as Sql-server. :(

Comment: still nothing gonna be change here. my provided query will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
"SELECT (
           CASE 
                WHEN ((1.00 - sys_pay.org_rate) * trans.txn_amt) < (trans.txn_amt - sys_pay.org_rate_limit) THEN 
                     agent_pay_max
                ELSE agent_pay_current
           END
       )
FROM   sys_org
       INNER JOIN trans
            ON  sys_org.mid = trans.mid
       INNER JOIN sys_pay
            ON  sys_pay.mid = sys_org.mid
ORDER BY
       txn_date DESC"
```

**OR**

```
"SELECT (
           CASE 
                WHEN ((1.00 - sys_pay.org_rate) * trans.txn_amt) < (trans.txn_amt - sys_pay.org_rate_limit) THEN (trans.txn_amt - sys_pay.org_rate_limit)
                ELSE ((1.00 - sys_pay.org_rate) * trans.txn_amt)
           END
       )            agent_pay_return
FROM   sys_org
       INNER JOIN trans
            ON  sys_org.mid = trans.mid
       INNER JOIN sys_pay
            ON  sys_pay.mid = sys_org.mid
ORDER BY
       txn_date     DESC"
```

agent_pay_return will be the return value as per case checked.

Comment: Shoudn't I define agent_pay_current first?

Comment: why you want to define it, we are doing conditional check nothing else so we don't require to give alias.

Comment: agent_pay_max and agent_pay_current is alias that I wanna use in templates,not fields name.

Comment: "Unknown column 'agent_pay_max' in 'field list"

Comment: I think you may not get the both values, agent_pay_max and agent_pay_current - as per case checking it will return only one, for other you can set other variable with that condition For example: ((1.00 - sys_pay.org_rate) * trans.txn_amt) as agent_pay_current

Comment: I found I got duplicate rows when use that SQL even though I add DISTINCT after select,any help?

Answer (score 0):

ms sql-server limit is like that

```
"SELECT TOP 10 (
    CASE WHEN (1.00 - sys_pay.org_rate)*trans.txn_amt as agent_pay_current 
    < (trans.txn_amt - sys_pay.org_rate_limit) as agent_pay_max 
    THEN agent_pay_max 
    ELSE agent_pay_current END)
    FROM sys_org 
    INNER JOIN trans ON sys_org.mid = trans.mid 
    INNER JOIN sys_pay ON sys_pay.mid = sys_org.mid 
    ORDER BY txn_date DESC"
```

And delete the Comma before the from. thanks to @rajeshmpanchal

Have not discovered another issue.

Comment: there should not be comma after this line "ELSE agent_pay_current END),"